# javascript to jquery conversions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function which returns a function. What does it mean ?

```
function CheckShadowBounds(rounded) {
    return function() {
    };
}
```

How can I convert it to jQuery ?

Comment: The code as you presented it doesn't do anything...

Comment: No, I mean what is purpose of returning a function from a function ?

Comment: You cant 'convert something to jQuery'. jQuery is javascript, javascript is jQuery.

Comment: `A closure is formed by returning a function object that was created within an execution context of a function call from that function call and assigning a reference to that inner function to a property of another object. Or by directly assigning a reference to such a function object to, for example, a global variable, a property of a globally accessible object or an object passed by reference as an argument to the outer function call. e.g:-`

Answer (score 4):

It means it returns a function. Functions are first class objects and can be passed around just like strings, arrays, etc, etc.

The purpose of this example is to define `rounded` for the function. The same instance of `rounded` will be used every time the returned function is called.

You can't convert it to jQuery. jQuery is a set of predefined JavaScript functions that do things lots of people want to do, but which are relatively complex (often because of browser incompatibilities). This is not something that is relatively complex, so jQuery doesn't provide a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

See Joel Spoelsky's intro to functional programming in JS to understand some ways a function returning a function can be useful: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html

This shouldn't need any changes to work in JQuery.